# Datetimepicker generates concurrent saves error in breezejs / knockout when moving the time / date slider too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, breeze, datetimepicker

I use the datetimepicker from [trentrichardson](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) in a Knockout / Breeze / Typescript webapp. The entity (called Issue) is automatically saved when changes are made.

But when I change the slider on the datetimepicker, the knockout observable is changed rapidly multiple times. So frequently that I get an breeze error:

> Error: Concurrent saves not allowed - SaveOptions.allowConcurrentSaves
>   is false

When I change the slider just a bit, no error is generated and the entity is stored correctly. I've tried to set the rateLimit, but that does not seem to work.

This is how I save the changes:

```
public SubscribeToChanges() {
    this.BreezeEntityManager.entityChanged.subscribe((data: breeze.EntityChangedEventArgs) => {
        if (data.entityAction == breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
            this.BreezeEntityManager.saveChanges()
            .fail((error) => alert("Failed: " + error));
        }
    });
}
```

That compiles to JavaScript:

```
 this.BreezeEntityManager.entityChanged.subscribe(function (data) {
      if (data.entityAction == breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
           _this.BreezeEntityManager.saveChanges().fail(function (error) {
               return alert("Failed: " + error);
          });
      }
  });
```

I've tried to set the rateLimit so there should not be so many update. I did this with the following code:

```
this.BreezeEntityManager
            .executeQuery(query)
            .then((data) =>{
                this.Issue(<Issue>data.results[0]);
                this.Issue().Deadline.extend({ rateLimit: 5000});
            })
            .fail((error) => alert("Failed: " + error));
```

That compiles to JavaScript:

```
this.BreezeEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                            _this.Issue(data.results[0]);
                            _this.Issue().Deadline.extend({ rateLimit: 5000 });
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            return alert("Failed: " + error);
                        });
```

Since this did not worked, I've also tried to set the rateLimit on the entity (Issue) itself in the constructor:

```
        this.Issue.extend({
            rateLimit: {
                timeout: 5000,
                method: "notifyWhenChangesStop"
            }
        });
```

but no result.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Issue().Deadline"/>
```

The Issue is created like this:

```
public Issue: KnockoutObservable<Persistent.Issue> = ko.observable<Persistent.Issue>();
```

How do I prevent the datetimepicker from generating concurrent saves?

Comment: It looks as if you are referencing c# in your question. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: There is no C# code in the above issue. It is Typescript, which just looks like C#, and that is at compile time translated to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using knockout 3.1, this should work:

```
this.Issue().Deadline.extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, 
                                            method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" }
                            });
```

From doc:

> notifyWhenChangesStop — The notification happens after no changes have
>   occured to the observable for the specified period of time. Each time
>   the observable changes, that timer is reset, so notifications cannot
>   happen if the observable continuously changes more frequently than the
>   timeout period.

Documentation **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)**

### If you are using a previous version, use throttle instead:

(rateLimit is new as of 3.1)

```
this.Issue().Deadline.extend({ throttle: 500});
```

Documentation **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html)**

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either, although I agree that this should work . . .

Comment: Are you sure the notification is raised by Deadline ? Try to add the extender on all observables that might be concerned

Comment: That is a good point. When setting a breakpoint in the event handler, the property data.entity._$typeName is set to "Issue:#Persistent". But setting the rateLimit on Issue does not do the trick. I'm wondering if the fact that Issue is assigned a breeze entity (this.Issue(<Issue>data.results[0])) has something to do with this issue.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with TypeScriptn but don't you actually add the extend too late? It should be added when you create your object, but I feel like you add it on update. Could you post the generated javascript?

Comment: Typescript is converted to plain Javascript, so at runtime there is only Javascript. I've already added the extend when creating the Issue object, but problem exists. I think I look into a custom binding for the datetimepicker

Comment: I understand Typescript is converted to javascript, that's why I asked for the generated javascript :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your comment carefully. I've edited my post to include JavaScript and the HTML.

Comment: @Richard Can you provide the way you create your Issue too?

Comment: I've updated the post with how the issue is created.